# Inconsistent AABB collision detection

Tags: javascript, 2d, collision-detection

I asked this question on gamedev yesterday but nobody has replied.

I'm making a 2d endless jumper as my first game and I'm running into some problems with the one-way collision detection between the player and the platform.

Collisions are detected correctly most of the time but occasionally the player inexplicably falls through the platform.

I suspect that it is ghosting through the platforms but I can't see why and I'm too close to it to be able to identify the source of the problem.

My code:

```
for (i = 0, len = this._platforms.length; i < len; i++) {
        var p = this._platforms[i];

        // Get difference between center of player and center of platform
        p.proximity = Math.abs(p.x / 2 - player.x / 2) + Math.abs(p.y / 2 - player.y / 2);

        if (p.closest()) {
            if (p.collision()) {
                player.onplatform = true;
                player.y = p.y - player_s_right.height;
            } else {
                player.onplatform = false;
            }
        }
 ... 
}
```

It loops through the platform objects, running the collision test only if the current platform is the closest one to the player.

Here are the closest() and collision() checks respectively:

```
// Return whether platform is the closest one to the player
Platform.prototype.closest = function() {

    var minprox = Math.min.apply(Math, platforms._platforms.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.proximity;
    }));

    return this.proximity === minprox;
}

// Collision detection
Platform.prototype.collision = function() {

// offset of 15 pixels to account for player's bandana
    var px = player.direction > 0 ? player.x + 15 : player.x,
        px2 = player.direction > 0 ? player.x + player_s_right.width : player.x + player_s_right.width - 15,
        py = player.y + player_s_left.height,
        py2 = player.y + player_s_right.height + player.yvelocity,

        platx2 = this.x + platform_s.width,
        platy2 = this.y + platform_s.height;

    if (((px > this.x && px < platx2) || (px2 > this.x && px2 < platx2)) && (py2 >= this.y && py2 <= platy2) && py <= this.y) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

If anyone can shed some light on this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Usually this occurs if an object is moving too fast. Basically, in frame 1 they aren't close enough to an object to consider it a collision. In frame 2 due to the change in position given a velocity, they're now past the object. Imagine a 1x1 square moving toward a 1x1 square at 2 units per frame. If the first starts at an odd position (where their x and y values are odd) and the second at an even position, a collision will never occur. Check out raycasting for a way to deal with this.

Comment: I have added the player's yvelocity to the y value I check against for the collision so that the velocity is essentially an extension of the player. Does this not prevent such a case from happening?

Comment: Generally, yes. I'd have to pick through it for a while to find the solution. I'd suggest drawing rectangle showing where exactly you're doing collision detections then, if possible, slow down your game and just watch where the rectangles are. That's how I've fixed a lot of collision issues.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to help. I'll give that a shot

Comment: If it helps, [here](https://github.com/Shaffan/Ninjump) is a link to the full source code.